# Finding text from text box of user control

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have following usercontrol named  ProductMenu.ascx:

[image]

**CS:**

```
public partial class ProductMenu1 :System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }
  public void SetTxt(String Cusine,String PName,String Description,String serving)
  {

      lblProductName.Text = PName;
      lblDescription.Text = Description;
      lblServing.Text = serving;
      lblPrice.Text = ""+230;
  }


}
```

I am adding this user control to page page **ProductMenu.aspx** as follows

**CS:**

```
public void PupulateMenu(DataTable dt)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    ProductMenu1 PM = (ProductMenu1)Page.LoadControl("ProductMenu.ascx");
    PM.SetTxt(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString(),dt.Rows[i][3].ToString(),dt.Rows[i]
    [4].ToString(),dt.Rows[i][6].ToString());
    Button addtocart = (Button)PM.FindControl("btnAddToCart");
    addtocart.CommandArgument = dt.Rows[i][3].ToString() + ";" + dt.Rows[i]
    [8].ToString() + ";" + dt.Rows[i][5].ToString();
    addtocart.Click += new EventHandler(addtocatr_Click);
    pnlProductMenu.Controls.Add(PM);
  }
}
```

Following is the function on page **ProductMenu.aspx** for adding the user control **text box quantity** to the cart.

```
private  void addtocatr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string[]  arg = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)
  (sender)).CommandArgument.ToString().Split(';');
  ProductMenu1 pm=new ProductMenu1 ();
  string txtQty = ((TextBox)pm.FindControl("txtQty")).Text;
}
```

but I am unable to access the textbox (txtqty) text in the method  addtocatr_Click. I don't know what exactly the problem is. Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error or exception is coming?

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to write a property to access the `TextBox` Value

Like

```
public string QtyText
{
    get { return txtQty.Text; }
}
```

and access using

```
string txtQty = pm.QtyText;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am unable to access the textbox (txtqty) text

Give your control a public readonly property called Quantity.  Use the get routine to `return txtqty.text;`